# Error Duplicados PHP+MySQL en INSERT maestro-detalle, cuando hay problemas de saturacion del servidor

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

Tengo un grave problema con mi procedimiento de inserción de pedidos en mi maestro-detalle.

Inserta normalmente cuando no hay problemas de saturación en mi servidor de hosting; pero cuando "al parecer" hay un corte o bloqueo, se genera otra vez todo el procedimiento y como yo mismo genero mi llave que es el año+n_pedido, me genera 2 pedidos iguales, incluso descontandome el stock que genera los disparadores de la tabla.

Incluso he migrado de proveedor de hosting, pensando que era problema de saturación por uno con  mejores recursos (mas caro), pero despues de días que ya no tenía duplicados, volvió a suceder!

Es decir solo se presenta menos veces dichos duplicados. Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar, ya probé de todo y no doy con la solución, si es mi código PHP o MySQL o el proveedor de hosting.

Este es mi código:

```
$id_usuario=$_POST['id_usuario'];
$total=$_POST['total'];
$array = $_POST['array'];

//database constans
define('DB_HOST', '');
define('DB_USER', '');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_NAME', '');

$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
/* comprobar la conexión */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Falló la conexión a MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima');
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$ano = date("Y");

// consulta que cuenta los registros del ano actual
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT MAX(n_pedido) AS cont FROM Pedido_cabecera WHERE ano_eje=$ano;");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($cont);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
     $cont++;
}
if(is_null($cont)) { $cont = 1; }

$conn->autocommit(FALSE);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Pedido_cabecera(ano_eje, n_pedido, id_usuario, fecha_hora, total, estado)
                VALUES(".$ano.",".$cont.",'".$id_usuario."','".$now."',".$total.",'0');");
    if ( $stmt ) {
        $rc = $stmt->execute();
        if ( $rc ) {
            $detalle = array();
            $data = json_decode($array,true);
            foreach($data as $row) {
                $precio = number_format(floatval($row['importe']) / floatval($row['cantidad']), 4);
                array_push($detalle, "(".$ano.",".$cont.",".$row['id_producto'].",".$row['cantidad'].",".$precio.",".$row['costo_venta'].",".$row['importe'].",".$row['stock_actual'].")");
            }
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Pedido_detalle(ano_eje,n_pedido,id_producto,cantidad,precio_venta,costo_venta,importe,stock_actual) VALUES" . implode(", ", $detalle));
            if ( $stmt ) {
                $rc = $stmt->execute();
                if ( $rc ) {
                    $conn->commit();
                }else{
                    $conn->rollback();
                    die('execute() ErrorDet: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
                }
            }else{
                die('prepare() ErrorDet: ' . $array . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
            }
        }else{
            $conn->rollback();
            die('execute() ErrorCab: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
        }
    }else{
        die('prepare() ErrorCab: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
    }

$conn->autocommit(TRUE);

echo $cont;
$stmt->close();
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Soy nuevo en programación web, así que no veo nada raro en tu código (aunque hay cosas que no entiendo). Podrías hacer tu llave (año+no_pedido) unique, para que no se pueda insertar la segunda vez que intente la inserción...

Comment: Es la llave primaria, pero al volver a ejecutarse el código, genera un nuevo pedido (ya que el contador aumenta); pero con los mismos datos que el anterior pedido, tanto cabecera (maestro) como en el detalle.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios problemas con tu codigo, pero, el problema principal radica en que el usuario puede usar F5 y recargar la pagina reenviando los datos, tu codigo asigna un nuevo "ID" sin checar por el "re-submit".

Tienes dos opciones:

```
1.- al crear la forma envias el siguiente ID disponible con esto al intentar grabar un ID existente se genera un error (que ya estas manipulando).
2.- Puedes checar el ultimo registro de la tabla y compararlo con el POST, en caso de que los datos sean iguales, responde con el mismo error "ya existe", sin embargo...
```

Para obtener el nuevo ID estas contando uno por uno los registros de la tabla, lo que consume mucho tiempo, usa count(campo) en tu query, ej.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(n_pedido) AS cont FROM Pedido_cabecera WHERE ano_eje=$ano;");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($cont);
$stmt->fetch()
$cont++;
```

En este ejemplo (modificando tu codigo) $cont ya contiene el numero de registros actuales en la tabla y por eso se le suma uno al final, pero, esto tampoco funciona, ya que si se borra algun registro la cantidad de registros sera igual al ID-1 por lo que intentara grabar sobre el ultimo ID, por lo tanto y pensando en algo "bulletproff", sugiero que leas el ultimo registro agregado y sumes uno, ej.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT n_pedido AS cont FROM Pedido_cabecera WHERE ano_eje=$ano ORDER BY n_pedido DESC LIMIT 1;");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($cont);
$stmt->fetch()
$cont++;
```

Espero que esto te sirva y sea de utilidad.